# On GCP is there a way to configure App Engine + Cloud Datastore application with multi-region availability?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

**Context**

App Engine service is regional. Cloud Datastore though has multi-region locations where data is replicated in multiple regions within the same location as described here, It is not clear whether App Engine service also has multi-regional availability when one of the multi-region locations are used. We understand that App Engine uses multiple zones within a region to provide high availability but the requirement document is asking for a multi-region (active-active) App Engine set up.

**Solution Option**

We are thinking of the following set up as a way to achieve an Active-Active AppEngine+Datastore combination in 2 different regions.

- Use 2 different GCP projects to host the same AppEngine+Datastore
  application in 2 different regions. One of these will be primary and
  the other will be an active standby.
- Use scheduled jobs to export
  data from Datastore data from primary region to secondary region
  subject to import/export guidelines described here.
- In order to automate data export and import a combination of App Engine cron jobs
  and/or Cloud Functions can be used.
- Frequency of data back up can be determined by application RPO and RTO needs.

**Rationale for Cloud Datastore Export and Import**

There is at the moment no other built-in (GCP managed) replication mechanism for Datastore data replication across regions.

**Questions**

Q1: Is there a way to configure App Engine + Cloud Datastore application with multi-region availability? The requirement is to have an active-active configuration in 2 regions. Is this possible and what is the correct way to do this?

Q2: In order to use Solution Option given above, there needs to be a way to map the domain names of primary and secondary App Engine applications to the same DNS name and use some kind of weighted DNS mapping to enable automatic routing of traffic to secondary App Engine instance when failover is needed,

Q3: Is there a recommended way of doing this? Does Cloud DNS or HTTP(s) Loadbalancer - in combination with Stackdriver provide a way to accomplish this? (Note - App Engine applications do not have a public static IP, GCP provides domain names instead.)
Is there any recommendation from Google on the best way to automate Datastore export and import? The easiest solution is to use gcloud command line within a VM. There are also ways to automate this with App Engine Cron jobs and/or Cloud Functions? What does Google recommend?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you are trying to accomplish is not possible the way you describe it.

With multi-region datastore you already have good availability for the database. If your goal is availability of your instance, then one option is to connect to the same database from an instance belonging to a different project, or compute engine or a completely different platform altogether. The details of doing this are available at

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#other-platforms

The only challenge with this is the extra latency but you will be able to avoid a lot of complexity associated with the import/export and sync processes. Assuming regional level outages are exception, you pay for this extra latency very rarely.

I am not sure how the custom domain setting can be done with this strategy where the domain resolves to the instances on the other region when there is an outage. You may be better off using other compute options of GCP than using app engine but still leverage cloud datastore for multi-region availability of the entire stack.

Comment: Comments to improve this answer. 1) App Engine Standard only supports one region per project. Therefore, Q2 is not possible. 2) Cloud DNS has no features to detect or reroute failed traffic. 3) The Google Frontend (GFE) manages traffic distribution and routing for App Engine Standard. 4) Google HTTP Load Balancers do not support App Engine Standard as a backend.